# How to keep elasticsearch server up and running 24/7

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack, digital-ocean

My server is hosted on digital ocean. I am facing one issue with the elasticsearch server. It is stopping after a few hours of being idle. How can I resolve this and make it up and running all the time?

Comment: do you get any errors?  have you tried asking them about it?

Comment: I have several instances on DO myself, and none is going down. Can you share the logs that you see around the time this happens?

Comment: @Val you have several instances of elastic search server on DO? Did you make any changes to the elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: @Clayton I am not getting any error. The server is just stopping after sometime.

Comment: have you contacted your host about the issue?

Comment: @Clayton No, I did not because I thought It was some problem with my elasticsearch setup and they wont help me out in that regard

Comment: can you post any of your configuration?  maybe there is something else on the server that is killing it?

Comment: @Subhajit I have one ES instance per server. If you have many ES instances on a single server, you might run into sharing issues and you must definitely modify the configuration in order to make them run side to side. Feel free to share the configuration(s)  you have.

Comment: @Val I followed this to configure my elasticsearch server --> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04  . All i did was uncomment the lines that were specified in this document

Comment: @Clayton i used https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04 to configure my elasticsearch.yml file

Comment: are you using the latest version of elasticsearch?

Comment: I am using elasticsearch 1.9.0 @Clayton

Comment: well, since your host isn't going to help you, maybe you could try the latest version of elasticsearch: 2.0.2

Comment: There never has been any version 1.9.0 of Elasticsearch. The latest version is 2.1.1.

Comment: @Clayton I installed the latest version of elasticsearch still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I found this discussion that may be similar to your problem: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10101 .. what is your output after running `uname -a` ? Is it similar to the comment in that GH discussion?  Read all the comments there and maybe something will apply to you... hope you figure it out

Comment: @Clayton what is the memory configuration of your droplet on which you are running elasticsearch? Rather what is the ideal server configuration to run elastic?

Comment: I don't know anything about elasticsearch actually, the problem is harder to track down since you say you are not experiencing any errors besides that it is randomly stopping.  Is there truly nothing in your /var/log/elasticsearch file??

Comment: @Clayton This is my log file http://dpaste.com/13E9109

Comment: Honestly, this is something you should have found in the beginning and included in your original question.  I didn't know enough about elasticsearch to ask you about the log file early on.... anyway, I don't know how to help you. I googled the error but don't enough to help.  It might be easiest just to repost the question but include the errors that are in the log file rather. Specifically mention the IndexNotFoundException issue and the whole file... good luck.

Comment: The pastebin has deleted, you may want to repost.

Comment: @speedplane, Sorry for that. This is the link -->http://dpaste.com/1Z4X9FS